# Splitting column data into different html columns based on their value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below mysql query to fetch numerical values from the database.

```
 $sql = "SELECT PromA, PromB, PromC, PromD FROM Mytable limit 100";
```

and this php snippet:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
echo  "</td><td>". $row["PromA"] . "</td><td>" . $row["PromB"]. "</td><td>". $row["PromC"]. "</td><td>". $row["PromD"].  "</td></tr>";

       }
```

I'd like to split the column values into html columns according to their numerical value in ascending order. The mysql table columns have numerical values in no particular order, and I'd like to put them in ascending order, if the value is not present for a row, then it'd be left empty. How can I do this?

so the end result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: the html shows a table with columns 1-10 with 5 rows so how you expect to get that from the given sql is a mystery. Incidentally the php/html snippet shown seems invalid as it begins with a closing table cell and ends with closing table row tag.

Comment: This is a sample only. I am not sure if it is possible. What I need is to extract numbers and put them in ascending order in the html table if possible. For example, Prom A may have any value starting from 1 to 10, and the other columns as well. but  they don't have the same value at the same row.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly. How about adding `ORDER BY PromA ASC, PromB ASC, PromC ASC ... ` to your query ?

Comment: but this wouldn't give the tabular result I want.

Comment: Stores the values ​​in a 1D array, then sort it. Use a loop to browse and display it.

Comment: I understand a little more clearly now having read your comment but am I correct in thinking that `PromA` in the sql equates to `col1` in the html etc etc??

Comment: no, it is not like that. PromA is not equal to Col1. if PromA has 1, then 1 goes to Col1. if it has 2, then it goes col2. if there is 3, then it goes Col3, etc. this is same for all.